# AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

Tags: python, pandas, csv

So I made a function where when called, it will import the column (`['Net Sales']`) of the `dataFrame` from `example2.csv`, for later to export to `example1.xlsx` with some parameters. The error raised when I tried to find the sum of the data from the column (`['Net Sales']`).

Why did this happen? How do I successfully execute the code as I intended?

```py
import pandas as pd


def mokacsv(file_name):
    importing = pd.read_csv(file_name)
    column_netsales = importing["Net Sales"]
    sum_of_netsales = sum(column_netsales)
    sum_of_netsales.to_excel(
        "example1.xlsx", index=False, header=True, startrow=5, startcol=3
    )

print(mokacsv(r"example2.csv"))
```

Error raised:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'to_excel'

[image: The data in (['Net Sales']) are as attached here.]

P.S this is my second week of python3, it might be a very amateur question

Comment: As indicated by the error message, `sum_of_netsales` is a float - the sum that you calculated on the line before. How do you expect it to have a `to_excel` method?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? The result of `sum(column_netsales)` is a single `float` value which is the sum of whole column. Its like let's say we have a variable `a = 7`, and now what you are trying to do is : `a.to_excel()` that's why it gives you error, as `.to_excel` is used with dataframe but you have a float variable

Comment: @MuhammadHassan is there not a way where I can calculate the sum of the data in the image file and export it to excel?

Comment: You can try: `pd.DataFrame(data={'Sum':[your_df[your_desired_column].sum()]}).to_excel("output.xlsx", sheet_name='Sheet_name_1')`

Comment: @MuhammadHassan Where do I put that line of code for my function? or do I independently run that code?

Comment: What do you want to achieve? Whether do you want the column sum to be on the last row of the column and then save column as excel file or you want just the sum and export the sum as excel file (i.e excel file will have just one value)

Comment: So basically I want the function to be able to input a `.csv` file and import the data from the `[Net Sales]` column, count the sum, then export the sum to a `.xlsx` file. Then I'll save the `.xslx` file. Bottom line, I want to automate the process of opening a `.csv` file and count the sum of Net Sales, then copy-paste the sum to a different `.xlsx` file. I usually do it manually but now I want to be doing it with python.

Comment: Just to state the obvious: `sum_of_netsales` is a float, as in a single number. If you *do* use one of the above comments to save it to Excel, then you're going to get a spreadsheet with exactly one cell of contents. Which sorta defeats the point of being a spreadsheet. Have you considered outputting to a simple txt file or even the console, since it's a single output value?